# Powershell PSModule unc path

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I am adding a UNC path, like "\\server\share\modules" to the user session env variable PSModule like this:

```
$env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";\\server\share\modules"
```

But, when I try to load a module from this path, I get an error

```
PS C:\> Import-Module WS_XML_MODULE
Import-Module : The specified module 'WS_XML_MODULE' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module WS_XML_MODULE
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (WS_XML_MODULE:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Listing all the available modules, which should show the UNC path available modules, doesn't show me any of the UNC folder modules...

```
Get-Module -listavailable
```

Anybody knows why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go this working...

I took a look at the system modules folder and the syntax of the folders and files are exacly the same, with dots separating words like Microsoft.Powershell.Something

I then changed the name of the PSM1 file to the same and got them into folder with the same name and BAmm.. in a heartbeat loaded all my modules.

Answer (score 0):

Place the "WS_XML_MODULE.psm1 and WS_XML_MODULE.psd1" in the folder named "WS_XML_MODULE".

Make sure "WS_XML_MODULE" folder is located in  "\\server\share\modules"

Note: Don't include the Module name in Path